# Known issues with gzip and IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, gzip

I read that some versions of IE6 have known issues with gzip compression, but I have found little explanation as to what these issues are. What are the known issues with gzip compression and IE6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241822/1265795#1265795).

If you are using Apache there is information at the [Ultimate IE6 > Cheatsheet: How To Fix 25+ Internet Explorer 6 Bugs](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#gzip-ie6) on how to work around it:

> Some versions of IE6 prior to the XP
> SP2 update may have trouble with files
> that have been served using GZip
> compression. Fortunately, [Seb
> Duggan](http://sebduggan.com/) found a [IE6 GZip bug
> solution](http://sebduggan.com/posts/ie6-gzip-bug-solved-using-isapi-rewrite) using [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/)
> for Apache.
>
> Seb's solution is to place the
> following code in the *httpd.conf*
> file in the ISAPI_Rewrite installation
> directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} MSIE\ [56]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:User-Agent} !SV1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$
RewriteHeader Accept-Encoding: .* $1
```

Comment: Is there an IE6 GZip bug solution for IIS 6?  Thanks.

Comment: You should probably link directly to Seb Duggan's site instead, because the text you're quoting is wrong. There is no "ISAPI_Rewrite for Apache". ISAPI_Rewrite is a module for IIS that aims to be compatible with Apache's mod_rewrite. [But `RewriteHeader` doesn't work in Apache.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733573/disabling-compression-for-ie-pre-sp2-with-apache-mod-rewrite)