# Are there known problems with IE6 / IE8, GZip compression and OC4J?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, gzip

i found this code in an app i'm working on and i was wondering if it still makes sense.

```
 final String ua = request.getHeader("user-agent");
 doFilterChainDeflater(!ua.contains("MSIE"), request,
                                  response, filterChain);

private void doFilterChainDeflater(boolean deflate,
                                   HttpServletRequest request,
                                   HttpServletResponse response,
                                   FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,
                                                                   ServletException {
    log.debug(BrowserNavigationFilter.class.getSimpleName() +
              " deflate output for " + request.getRequestURI());
    DeflaterResponseWrapper wrappedResponse =
        new DeflaterResponseWrapper(deflate, response);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, wrappedResponse);
    wrappedResponse.finishResponse();
}
```

This compress the response only if the browser is not IE (this is because IE6 had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456112/known-issues-with-gzip-and-ie6), how strange).
The code i'm mantaining is fairly old and most of our users have switched to IE8. Now i'm asking two things

- are there known problem with Gzip and IE8?
- how can i detect wheter the user has IE8 or is still on IE6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past when working with IE6 it had problems handling compressed files that smaller than a certain size (can't recall what that size was), also it could not handle compressed CSS files.