# Fiddler recorded content-length vs WebTest result page bytes

Tags: visual-studio, webtest

I am new in visual studio 2008 Web test. I tried to record to fiddler my web site which deployed in IIS 6.0 and GZIP compression is enabled. I saved the session generated by fiddler to .webtest file extension. I attached the webtest file to vs 2008 and run the web test. I notice that the result of webtest page bytes is different from the content-lenght or body recorded in fiddler.

**with GZIP compression:**

Webtest bytes vs fiddler body

**914,330 vs 45,840**

I also try with **no gzip compression**: This is the result bytes from webtest result:
Bytes

Webtest bytes vs fiddler body

**1,181,623 vs 406,353**

Question: In webtest result, does the column Bytes represent the content-length of the page? if not what does the Bytes column represent?

I also notice that if the GZIP compression is enabled the webtest result response content-length is not shown in the response tab?

Can anyone explain the difference of the result?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the difference a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the Visual Studio load test is not emulating IE 6 without Gzip compression support.
Otherwise check [the content header is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241822/why-is-gzip-compression-with-internet-explorer-not-working).

Having a look at the traffic captured by fiddler and the playback from a webtest, I would be tempted to put any difference down to the fact that the Visual Studio load test is going to request and record a lot fewer items than fiddler will.

Comment: I've check the request Accept-Encoding: GZIP. I already try to replace the browser type of localtestrun.testrunconfig but still the result of page bytes is not the same as the result of fiddler content-lenght?

Comment: How much is the difference? Enough to represent unzipped files?

Answer (score 0):

with GZIP compression:
This is the result bytes from webtest result:

### Bytes

914,330

And this was the result from fiddler:

### Body

45,840

I also try with no gzip compression:
This is the result bytes from webtest result:

### Bytes

1,181,623

And this was the result from fiddler:

### Body

406,353

Question: In webtest result, is the column Bytes represents the content-length of the page? if not what is this Bytes column represents for?

I also notice that if the GZIP compression is enabled the webtest result response content-length is not shown in the response tab?

Answer (score 0):

Ok but I'm not yet trying it to load test. I usually check first the webtest that is why I'm wondering that the response content-length of web test is different from fiddler's content-length.