# IE8 not loading CSS on occasion

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

This is killing me guys

http://publish.uwo.ca/~mchum/index.htm

Displays fine in FF, IE9. Some minor layout issues in Chrome, and mobile Safari

Whenever I try to load from the server in IE7, IE8, it's a crapshoot. It's usually more reliable on first-load, but if you press F5 (or even ctrl-F5), it won't load completely.

Sometimes it will load some of the background, and sometimes it won't load the CSS or the javascript at all.

The strange thing is it only works after I've uploaded it to the server; it doesn't occur locally.

I'm quite the rookie here, and still learning quite a bit. I'm almost feeling I've bitten off way more can I chew. Some (merciful) assistance please!

Comment: Just refreshed it 20 times or so and it seems to work just fine (IE8 & IE8 Compatibility mode).

Comment: @user1473654 It's IE, don't ask ;)

Comment: Can you post some picture? Your website seems fine to me.(with IE, FF, Chrome)

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with Fiddler running?

Comment: Pictures:
http://publish.uwo.ca/~mchum/images/debugging/error1.jpg -- successful load
http://publish.uwo.ca/~mchum/images/debugging/error2.jpg -- loaded flash, CSS; no HTML/javascript
http://publish.uwo.ca/~mchum/images/debugging/error3.jpg -- loaded flash, some HTML content; no CSS/javascript
http://publish.uwo.ca/~mchum/images/debugging/error4.jpg -- loaded flash, javascript countdown, some HTML content; no CSS

Comment: publish.uwo.ca/~mchum/images/debugging/error5.jpg -- CSS, no flash/javascript

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your web server has GZIP compression enabled.  The post below talks about the headers you need to send so that IE handles your CSS and JS files consistently.  I have ran into this with IE6 but it appears it may still be an issue with at least IE7.

I am not positive this is the issue but it is worth looking into.

[Why is gzip compression with Internet Explorer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241822/why-is-gzip-compression-with-internet-explorer-not-working)

Comment: Hmm...this seems to be a bit over my capabilities...2 questions

1) Not good with code/syntax. What's the code that I need to inject? I'm assuming it's in the header of the HTML

2) I'm assuming I need a program to gzip the CSS file, and then upload it? Where can I find such a program? Or am I to assume that the server will do that automatically?

Comment: I reproduced it with Fiddler. What information should I be looking out for?

Initially, it loads but when the error starts up, it still shows its loading up the CSS and javascript but it won't download the background gif. And as evidenced by the complete alteration in html structure, i'm pretty sure it's not actually loading the css at all

Comment: The response header of each resource (css,js files) should have in the response header `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  If it is not doing this it will need to be configured at the web server level.  You wont be able to add any markup since we are talking about CSS and JS files.